# Expressing side effects in jsonapi response

Tags: json-api

I'm having en existential crisis on how to represent side effects in a jsonapi response.

Scenario:

I have a cart that contains items and a discount promotion 3for2.
If the cart contains 3 items eligible for that promotion and one is then removed. How can/should this side effect be communicated in the response.

Currently we return a representation of the cart, so the response will show what the cart contains but I'm keen on how to highlight that an item has been removed/updated as a result of an update/delete of another item.

Comment: can you update your scenario an example payload of what you're returning now?

Comment: @jdubjdub the current response isn't really important. This is purely about how you *would* represent side effects of a request within that response.  My only idea so far has been to return a 207 response (I know its not in the original spec - and it specifies an xml response!!) and add the extra information regarding the side-effects within the meta-data property.

Comment: not asking because i want to see current representation of the side effect - asking because i want to see the before/after state to see what the side effect actually looks like so i can give you a bit more substantive feedback than "use meta!" :)